# How can I get the textContent that appears before the parent tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to get the textContent of a h3 tag that appears above my parent div tag. The code is repeated, and adding an id is not an option for h3 tag.           Looking to do this in pure Javascript. My html currently is...

```
<h3>Some header</h3> //textContent I am trying to get.
<div class="panel panel-success"> //parent
    <div id="someid" class="panel-heading"></div> //child
    <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="padding-right: 1%"
                      onclick="myFunc(this.parentNode.id, what.goes.here?)"></span> //this needs to return parent id and the value of h3 tag
</div> 
<h3>Some other header</h3> //textContent I am trying to get.
<div class="panel panel-success"> //parent
    <div id="someid" class="panel-heading"></div> //child
    <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="padding-right: 1%"
                      onclick="myFunc(this.parentNode.id, what.goes.here?)"></span> //this needs to return parent id and some other tag when this span button is clicked
</div>
<h3>yet another header</h3> //textContent I am trying to get.
<div class="panel panel-success"> //parent
    <div id="someid" class="panel-heading"></div> //child
    <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="padding-right: 1%"
                      onclick="myFunc(this.parentNode.id, what.goes.here?)"></span> //this needs to return parent id and yet another header when clicked.
</div>
```

This piece of code repeats many times, and the textContent of h3 and the div id changes every time. I am trying to return the value of the textContent of the h3 tag that appears about the span button i am clicking relative to the div tag that appears during the click. The `h3` tag is not part of any other parent/child relationships, and is stand along...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementByID("someid").parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;

Edited

Comment: the `h3` tag is not the parent of the `div` tag. Its standalone

Comment: I just spoted that, Eelke's edited answer should be right with the previous sibling

Comment: I added more of the html code. this may explain why this doesnt work. the `h3` tags are not siblings of the `div` tag

Comment: I just tested this and it works for me. Make sure you are renaming "someid" to the actual id you are trying to work from edit > in your example, you use the same id for all three.  If it really looks like this, you will need to use getElementsByClass and work from the array it generates

Comment: i just tried `document.getElementByID(document.parentNode.id).parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent` but still didnt work.

Comment: No it should be something like: var x = document.getElementByID("someid-1").parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;    what is inside of the parentheses should either be the actual name of the id inside of quotes or a variable containing a string that is the name of the id without quotes.

Comment: document.parentNode.id returns NULL because you are asking for the parent of your entire document which is not a thing. Document is basicly the parent of everything.

Comment: thanks @Nosjimiki! `document.getElementById(this.parentNode.id).parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent` ended up working!

Answer (score 2):

From the `click` handler of the `span` you can access the above `h3` element like this:

```
this.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

Comment: That wouldnt work because that html piece is repeating... so there are a lot of different h3 tags. using `document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].textContent` returns only the first one it finds.

Comment: This solution works if know that you are looking for the n-th h3 tag on a page, but does not answer help with child-parent pairing.

Comment: In this case because the number of h3 tags are arbitrary. So i cant reliably predict the index number of for content

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: This returns nothing. just blank. i added more parts of the code to show the parent `div` tag closing before the next h3 tag starts

Comment: This is the DOM solution, for a procedural solution using the the same logic try:  document.getElementByID("someid").parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent

Comment: @securisec `onclick="console.log(this.parentNode.previousSibling.textContent)"` does not log blank right?

Comment: it appears that console.log doesnt even run. I changed the `console.log` to see if the browser picks it up, and it doesnt even run the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = document.querySelectorAll('h3');

let count = content.length;

if (count) {

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    alert(content[i].textContent);      
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kk49yLp/1/

Comment: This is a great solution, but doesnt work in this case because the number of h3 tags are arbitrary. So i cant reliably predict the index number of for content.

Comment: So if there are many `h3` you can get all the text of them with a for loop

Comment: I wouldnt need all the `h3` tags. just the one that is relative to the `onclick` `span`